# in the google-sheet script editor - Can't use subsrting function for a string in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

In my code the function calls for an array and a string,
it looks for a same begging in all the strings
within the array.

it goes like this:

```js
function tavnit(train, str) {
  f=0;
  i=0;
  while ((f==0) && (i<train.length))
  {
    var trs=train[i];
    if (str.substring(0,2)==trs.substring(0,2))
    {
      f=1
    }
    i++
  }
  return f;
}
```

There is no errors when saving, but when running there is -

> TypeError: Cannot find function substring in object XXVXJ. (line 7).

why doesn't it  reconize the string? and how should I make it recognize it?

Comment: Have you tried str.toString().substring(0,2) ? It really depends on what you are pushing as str.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - when google sheet function using a column as an argument -
It isn't simple array - it is a matrix that is implemented as an array of arrays:

```
[[tvg],[ttxv],[..],..]
```

So if you want to call the string, you first need to call the i array, and second to the first (and only) object in the array -

This the way I resolved it:

```
function tavnit(train, str) {
  f=0;
  i=0;
  while ((f==0) && (i<train.length))
 {
 line=train[i];
 trs=line[0];
 if (sametavnit(str, trs)==1)
  {
    return 1;
  }
 i++
 }
return f;
}
```